# Direct product of algebraic groups is an algebraic group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

I am attempting to verify that the product variety $G \times G'$ of algebraic groups with the direct product group structure is an algebraic group, though I'm running into trouble.  In particular, I'm having trouble showing that
$$\mu: (G\times G') \times (G\times G') \rightarrow G\times G'$$
is a morphism of ringed spaces.

The definition of morphism that I am using is that $\mu$ is a morphism if for every open $V \subseteq G \times G'$,
$$\mu\big\vert_{\mu^{-1}V}: f \mapsto f\mu$$
maps $\mathcal{O}_{G\times G'}(V)$ into $\mathcal{O}_{(G \times G') \times (G \times G')}(\mu^{-1}V)$ (where $\mathcal{O}$ is the sheaf of regular functions).

> > **EDIT:**
> >     I'm sure there is an easier way to do this using the universal property of $G \times G'$ as a direct product of varieties, but I'm still trying to do it without category theory to force myself to develop a better understanding of the concepts.
> >
> > So far what I've done is show that if you have a regular function $f$ on $G \times G'$, then you can get a regular function on $G \times G$.  Specifically, I've shown that if $f$ is regular at $(x_{1}x_{2}, x_{1}'x_{2}')$, there is an open neighborhood $B_{G}$ of $(x_{1}, x_{2})$ in $G \times G$ so that
> >     $$f\Big(\mu_{G}(b_{1}, b_{2}), x_{1}'x_{2}'\Big)$$
> >     is a rational function for all $(b_{1}, b_{2}) \in B_{G}$.
> >
> > The problem is that I don't see any way to extend this open neighborhood to one of $(x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{1}', x_{2}') \in (G \times G) \times (G' \times G')$ on which $f$ will be a rational function.

I assume I should use that
$$\mu_{G}: G \times G \rightarrow G,\qquad \mu_{G'}: G' \times G' \rightarrow G'$$
are morphisms of ringed spaces, but I can't see how to separate the two.  It seems like it might be alright in the case that $G, G'$ are affine and $V = G \times G'$, since in this case
$$\mathcal{O}(G \times G') \approx k[G \times G'] \approx k[G] \otimes k[G']$$
and I can break a regular function $f$ into $\sum f_{i} \otimes g_{i}$.  But otherwise, I don't see how to get something to apply $\mu_{G}$ to and something to apply $\mu_{G'}$ to.

I would like to mention that I am reading Springer's book on algebraic groups and he does not use schemes when he develops algebraic geometry.

Comment: Are you satisfied with the answer? If yes, please accept it, if not, you can ask further questions.

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$(G\times G')\times (G\times G')\cong (G\times G)\times (G'\times G')$$
as algebraic varieties.

Comment: Perhaps you should add that this isomorphism is as algebraic varieties.

Comment: @Vishal I don't usually edit year old answers but I guess the question's been edited anyway.

Comment: Perhaps it could be argued that clarity for future visitors is more important than the annoying bumping of the question to the main page?